# Postgresql Rails: Select random record within a certain range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have in my controller the following code to select a random photo:

```
@photo1 = @contest.photos.limit(1).order("RANDOM()")
```

I wish to select another random photo as @photo2 but its score attribute must be +/- 400 of @photo1's score. How would I do this?

Optional: I rather @photo2 be within +/- 200 of @photo1's score, and if there isn't any, then search +/- 400

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `where` with a range to generate a BETWEEN statement.

```
Photo.where(score: ((@photo1.score-200)..(@photo1.score+200)))
     .order("RANDOM()").take
```

Comment: Maybe you can try use sample method:  `Photo.where(score: ((@photo1.score-200)..(@photo1.score+200))).sample`

Comment: Plucking all the records out of the database to pluck a single one is very inefficient @ShallmentMo. If there are several thousand records it's sure to deadlock your server.